# CsvHelper MVC 5 C# Does not work

Tags: csv, asp.net-mvc-5, csvhelper

I have gone to GitHUb, followed the "One" tutorial on youtube about CSV and MVC. None of these work.(As far as I can tell!) Is there something in particular that needs to be configured to use CsvHelper on MVC 5 C#, Visual Studio 2013? I have a project to simply read a csv, txt file (tab-delimited) and (pipe-delimited) into a SQL Server 2014 table. I don't get why this is so difficult. Every article says"Simple", or "easy implementation". After installing the package, you should be able to just code. Now I'm getting errors and looking for resolutions to those. "Mapping", ini files and more. Is there a start to finish tutorial for using CsvHelper with C# MVC 5? All info or examples are 2012 and older. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
Controller:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using ReadCSV.Models;

namespace ReadCSV.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        public class Upload1ClassMap : CsvClassMap<Upload1List> 
        {
            public override void CreateMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.scansource).Name("scansource file");
                Map(m => m.Manufacturer).Name("manufacturer");
                Map(m => m.SKU).Name("SKU");
                Map(m => m.ScansourceSKU).Name("ScansourceSKU");
                Map(m => m.MSRP).Name("MSRP");
                Map(m => m.RoughSummary).Name("Rough Summary");
                Map(m => m.COST).Name("Cost");
                Map(m => m.Inventory).Name("Inventory");
                Map(m => m.Weight).Name("Weight");
                Map(m => m.CAT4th).Name("CAT 4th");
                Map(m => m.CAT1st).Name("CAT 1st");
                Map(m => m.CAT2nd).Name("CAT 2nd");
                Map(m => m.CAT3rd).Name("CAT 3rd");
                Map(m => m.ProductName).Name("Product Name");
                Map(m => m.Genre).Name("Genre");
                Map(m => m.ProductName2).Name("Prodcut Name2");
                Map(m => m.RougherSummary).Name("Rougher Summary");
                Map(m => m.Cat_4th).Name("Cat 4th");

                base.CreateMap();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string path = null;
            List<Upload1List> upload1List = new List<Upload1List>();
            try
            {

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upload\\" + fileName;
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
                    var Upload1List = csv.GetRecords<Upload1>();
                    foreach (var c in Upload1List)
                    {
                        Upload1List upload1Lists = new Upload1List();

                        try
                        {
                            upload1Lists.SKU = c.SKU;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //Do Nothing
                        }
                        upload1Lists.scansource = c.scansource;
                        upload1Lists.Manufacturer= c.Manufacturer;
                        upload1Lists.ScansourceSKU = c.ScansourceSKU;
                        upload1Lists.MSRP = c.MSRP;
                        upload1Lists.RoughSummary = c.RoughSummary;
                        upload1Lists.COST = c.COST;
                        upload1Lists.Inventory = c.Inventory;
                        upload1Lists.Weight = c.Weight;
                        upload1Lists.CAT4th = c.CAT4th;
                        upload1Lists.CAT1st = c.CAT1st;
                        upload1Lists.CAT2nd = c.CAT2nd;
                        upload1Lists.CAT3rd = c.CAT3rd;
                        upload1Lists.ProductName = c.ProductName;
                        upload1Lists.Genre = c.Genre;
                        upload1Lists.ProductName2 = c.ProductName2;
                        upload1Lists.RougherSummary = c.RougherSummary;
                        upload1Lists.Cat_4th = c.Cat_4th;



                        upload1List.Add(upload1Lists);

                    }
                 }

             }

            catch 
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "Upload failed";


            }




            return View();



        }
    }
}

Model:


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReadCSV.Models
{
    public class Upload1
    {

        public int scansource { get; set; }
        public int Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string ScansourceSKU { get; set; }
        public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
        public string RoughSummary { get; set; }
        public decimal COST { get; set; }
        public decimal Inventory { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public string CAT4th { get; set; }
        public string CAT1st { get; set; }
        public string CAT2nd { get; set; }
        public string CAT3rd { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string ProductName2 { get; set; }
        public string RougherSummary { get; set; }
        public string Cat_4th { get; set; }
    }

    public class Upload1List 
    {
        public int scansource { get; set; }
        public int Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string ScansourceSKU { get; set; }
        public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
        public string RoughSummary { get; set; }
        public decimal COST { get; set; }
        public decimal Inventory { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public string CAT4th { get; set; }
        public string CAT1st { get; set; }
        public string CAT2nd { get; set; }
        public string CAT3rd { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string ProductName2 { get; set; }
        public string RougherSummary { get; set; }
        public string Cat_4th { get; set; }

    }


}

Index:

{
@ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@model List<ReadCSV.Models.Upload1>

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<p>

    Upload your file
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>scansource</th>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>ScansourceSKU</th>
        <th>MSRP</th>
        <th>RoughSummary</th>
        <th>COST</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>CAT4th</th>
        <th>CAT1st</th>
        <th>CAT2nd</th>
        <th>CAT3rd</th>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>ProductName2</th>
        <th>RougherSummary</th>
        <th>Cat_4th</th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@c.scansource</th>
                <th>@c.Manufacturer</th>
                <th>@c.SKU</th>
                <th>@c.ScansourceSKU</th>
                <th>@c.MSRP</th>
                <th>@c.RoughSummary</th>
                <th>@c.COST</th>
                <th>@c.Inventory</th>
                <th>@c.Weight</th>
                <th>@c.CAT4th</th>
                <th>@c.CAT1st</th>
                <th>@c.CAT2nd</th>
                <th>@c.CAT3rd</th>
                <th>@c.ProductName</th>
                <th>@c.Genre</th>
                <th>@c.ProductName2</th>
                <th>@c.RougherSummary</th>
                <th>@c.Cat_4th</th>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table style="margin-top:150px">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="file">Filename:</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is the Error:

'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: See above^^. I am just trying to see the file displayed before I move to the task of table insertion. CsvHelper has been nothing but a headache.

Comment: And what line throws that exception? It is very clear for the error, that your code is not finding certain directory. Could you debug and see what's in your "path" variable?

Comment: path = "c:\\users\\administrator\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\ReadCSV\\ReadCSV\\upload\\newscansource-7162015.txt" Seems the path is getting the file.

Comment: 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/20/ROOT-1-130823062686364346): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/20/ROOT-1-130823062686364346): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. Noticed these also in the output window.